# Pandas: Applying a function to each group independently

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have the following data set:

```
ID      Duration
1          10         
1          20         
1          30
2          5
2          10
2          15
2          20
```

I want to add two columns, where the first is`SpeedMean` such that it is equal to `1` if the `Duration` in row i is less than the mean duration for a given `ID`, else 0.

For the second column, `SpeedMedian`, I want it equal to 1 if the `Duration` in row i is less than the median duration for a given `ID`, else 0.

The result should look like this:

```
ID      Duration     SpeedMean    SpeedMedian
1          10           1              1
1          20           0              0
1          30           0              0
2          5            1              1
2          10           1              1
2          15           0              0
2          20           0              0
```

I know I should use lambda x, but I'm new to pandas and would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: No need for lambda, though I guess you could.  Take a look at the documentation for groupby.  This should be a fairly straightforward application of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read up on `groupby` and `transformation` here

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#transformation

```
In [267]: df['SpeedMean'] = df.groupby('ID')['Duration'].transform(lambda s: s < s.median()).astype(int)

In [268]: df['SpeedMean'] = df.groupby('ID')['Duration'].transform(lambda s: s < s.mean()).astype(int)

In [269]: df['SpeedMedian'] = df.groupby('ID')['Duration'].transform(lambda s: s < s.median()).astype(int)

In [270]: df
Out[270]: 
   ID  Duration  SpeedMean  SpeedMedian
0   1        10          1            1
1   1        20          0            0
2   1        30          0            0
3   2         5          1            1
4   2        10          1            1
5   2        15          0            0
6   2        20          0            0
```